# Mock location for specific app only

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I want to set mock location for specific app only. So far, what I have understood is, if I set GPS provider with some mock location then, all apps accessing location through GPS will receive mocked location. Can it be made app specific? (means only specific app should see mocked location, all other apps will see true location.) If yes , how?